# WinRT: cannot release build my application

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

In my application I have 3 WinRT projects which I want to deploy. I want to deploy 1 of them; M.Survey.Windows which is dependent on the other 2.
I can build the projects OK, but when I try to build and deploy I run into difficulties.
I click on store -> Create App Packages, select No to upload to the Windows Store, click next and then Create. This does a build which fails, see below. How do I fix this?
[image]

[image]

The error messages say;
Error   1   The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key BlackSmallHeaderStyle  ...\M.Survey.Windows\UserControls\DimUserControl.xaml   137 25

Error   2   Unable to remove directory "obj\x86\Release\PackageLayout\". The process cannot access the file 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.dll' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the studio, then also deleting the .suo file, and possibly the .sdf file (and also restarting windows)? i know i know, but these solved problems like this for me many times.

Comment: I tried restarting VSand rebooting my PC. Although that didn't work, I found that when I made a change to the code I could rebuild, delete the MS dll (which I couldn't before) and I got a clean build.
Not sure this is the correct answer, I suppose you have to be persistent and you will get there eventually.

Comment: Glad you solved it. I think it would be useful to make a list of steps to try when facing a weird hard-to-explain compile errors.

Comment: As for the DLL error, I've found that killing the XDesProc.exe process frees up that DLL during a build.  Not sure if it's relevant anymore, but just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Killing XDesProc.exe also worked for me. 
XDesProc.exe is the Visual Studio XAML Designer tool.